# Remove points which contains pixels fewer than (N)

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, filter, scipy

I tried almost all filters in `PIL`, but failed.
Is there any function in numpy of scipy to remove the noise?
 Like Bwareaopen() in Matlab()?

e.g:

[image]

PS: If there is a way to fill the letters into black, I will be grateful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is what you want, but this works (uses Opencv (which uses Numpy)):

```
import cv2

# load image
fname = 'Myimage.jpg'
im = cv2.imread(fname,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# blur image
im = cv2.blur(im,(4,4))
# apply a threshold
im = cv2.threshold(im, 175 , 250, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im = im[1]
# show image
cv2.imshow('',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output (  image in a window ):
[image: Output image]

You can save the image using `cv2.imwrite`

Comment: +1 for the demonstration, but it seems strange to use openCV for this;  OP asked for numpy/scipy, and [blurring](http://scipy-lectures.github.com/advanced/image_processing/index.html#blurring-smoothing) and thresholding are well within the capabilities of these libraries.

Comment: @Junuxx I know, but originally even I said that, but he seems to be OK with it... Also, may I add that link into my answer??

Comment: opencv is ok, numpy/scipy would be better. Thank you again

Answer (score 15):

Numpy/Scipy can do morphological operations just as well as Matlab can.

See [scipy.ndimage.morphology](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_opening.html), containing, among other things, [`binary_opening()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_opening.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_opening), the equivalent of Matlab's `bwareaopen()`.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a try.

Comment: `binary_opening` seems to do a structural opening, which is not the same as an area opening that `bwareaopen` does.

Answer (score 13):

Numpy/Scipy solution: `scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_opening`. More powerful solution: use scikits-image.

```
from skimage import morphology
cleaned = morphology.remove_small_objects(YOUR_IMAGE, min_size=64, connectivity=2)
```

See http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/api/skimage.morphology.html#remove-small-objects